# What expression do you have in English as a counterpart to Japanese saying “Earthquake, Thunderbolt, Fire and Father"?

Tags: expressions

As you know, we Japanese experienced tremendous disasters of Magnitude 9
earthquake accompanied by tsunami exceeding 10 meter high in northeastern regions recently.

Living in the country always under the threat of big earthquakes, we have two popular saying that come to top of mind when we talk of disaster. One is “The great (natural ) disaster comes always when you have totally forgotten it.’ The other one is (the most fearful things under the sun are) “Earthquake, Thunderbolt, Fire and Father.” – Please note that the earthquake comes first.

Do you have popular saying or English cliché to be likened to such expressions? 
I'd like to teach them to my English enthusiast friends.

Comment: I suppose Father stands for a God? Yeah the news from Japan has been shocking. I do hope your family are all right.

Comment: @Cerberus No, I rather think it's referring to a literal fearsome father who has high expectations for his children.

Comment: @Cerberus: Remember Japan is mainly Shintoist and Buddhist in religion, where religion is followed at all; neither are monotheistic, so such a usage would be incorrect.

Comment: Bilare is right. Father refers to literal stern father, not God. Under feudalistic social system where Confucianism ruled in old day Japan, father used to have absolute power and dignity in family, and was fearsome existence (though at fourth place in fearsomeness ranking). Today, father lost all its dignity, power and gravity in most of households in modern Japan.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: What has replaced it?

Comment: Orbling. As a saying, Father still stays in four fearsomenesses. There’s no ‘received’ replacement. As a de- facto element, I would personally place Joblessness.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Intriguing.  The UK's unemployment rate is about 8% at the moment, compared to Japan's 4.9% (though that was before the current trouble). [Incidentally, when you respond directly to a person, prefix their name with @ otherwise they do not get notified.]

Comment: @Orbling: Yeah that's why I asked. I considered it a possibility that Japanese had some complicated word for "the spiritual, nature" that would be awkwardly translated as Father or God in some contexts, just as the polytheistic Greeks and Romans used the words God and nature in various ways. You will find Plato writing "God" all the time, without any monotheistic sense, but rather as "the divine", whatever that may be; it is still translated as "God". But I was wrong in any case, so why am I even rambling on.

Comment: @Cerberus: Well you take interesting rambles. ;-) Plato is often asserted to be a monotheist personally, even though the community he lived in was not.  Indeed a lot of the philosophical ground work on monotheism comes from Platoism, his concept of "The One" being an early foundation.

Comment: @Orbling: True. But his use of "God" did by no means indicate an anthropomorphic God. You will find the same use of *theos* all through Antiquity, beginning with the Presocratic philosophers, like Parmenides. I don't have the data available now but I think Homer did the same; Greek *theos* is usually something like *to theon*, "the divine", and is as often as not translated as "God", possibly due to tradition among translators, who were all Christians until the 18th-20th centuries.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yes, that was my thought on the matter earlier, I would like to look at the original Greek and form an opinion on the translation.  As the strong, nigh on compulsory religious view point the translators most likely held would colour their work.

Comment: @Cerberus:Thank you for your warm word for me and my family. I wasn’t in the mood to open the forum site for a while after experiencing 6+ seismic scale earthquakes in my neighborhood and watching its aftermath. Now I’m OK to be able to resume posting of questions.

Comment: @Joe Blow: It is not impolite, it is history, interesting points were raised that clarified a misunderstanding of the topic.

Comment: Point of interest: Because "Father" has lost it's power, this may have become an example of [Arson, Murder, Jaywalking](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking)

Comment: "Of all the pestilence's dire, Including famine, flood, and fire; By Satan and his imps rehearsed, The neighbors' children are the worst." - Stoddard King

Comment: The immediate quote that came to mind was [**thunderbolts and lightning, very, very frightening**](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Queen:Bohemian_Rhapsody), which I think you could actually use in a similar context, though it would require more of a humorous spin on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, in the UK, we don't suffer from natural disasters on the scale other countries do, so expressions related to them are very uncommon and I don't think any are in popular usage all over the country.

> The great (natural ) disaster comes always when you have totally forgotten it.

seems similar to 'Things always happen when you least expect them' although this is a rather generic expression.

> The other one is (the most fearful things under the sun are) “Earthquake, Thunderbolt, Fire and Father.”

This one however doesn't seem to have an English counterpart, as the most common natural disaster in the UK is flooding or snow related in some areas maybe there are reigional expressions which resemble this but none in common usage that I can think of.

Comment: Bit late to the party here, but the second reminds me of the expression Act of God: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_of_God

Answer (score 12):

What about 'the Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse', who from my memory of the book of Revelation are War, Famine, Pestilence and Death?

Comment: Death rides a pale horse...There are several books (Saxon series by Bernard Cornwell for example) that use the four horsemen to great thematic effect...I had a point, but I think I forgot it...Either way, +1. :)

Answer (score 4):

In English, the expression "[*Something happens*] when you least expect it" is common and is often completed with "Disaster strikes"--especially by insurance companies. So, your first saying will be familiar to westerners.

As far as the second saying, I also could not find any English equivalent. I did find [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=wGb4zNqYj10C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=sayings+about+natural+disasters&source=bl&ots=RB4FGy2aIi&sig=D6gbn3N3ReYIpE5GfahZ3O_K0JU&hl=en&ei=y0aHTeKrHMe3twegs9nOBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=earthquake&f=false) on Japanese sayings that includes English equivalents when it can, but it did not provide any for this particular saying.

Comment: Someone downvoted this, it would help to know why.

Comment: I was going to answer **Expect the unexpected!** for the first one but that is I guess a variant of @Callithumpian's first suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Two memorable hymn lines come to mind.

The first is from the final verse of *[Dear Lord and Father of Mankind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dear_Lord_and_Father_of_Mankind)* which asks  the "still, small voice of calm" (i.e. God) to

> speak through the earthquake, wind, and fire

while the second is in the final verse of *[Eternal Father, Strong to Save](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Father,_Strong_to_Save)* which is asking God to protect sailors

> from rock and tempest, fire and foe

but in both cases I expect the order to be simply for rhythm and rhyme, not importance.

Comment: As I said, anything like that in English would be bound to a statement to God.

Comment: I heard many men and women were crying “I lost all my family and house. I haven’t done nothing wrong. Why should I be punished and suffer agony like this?,” standing stunned on the debris. Their cries beat me. Is this God’s will? Why shoul he punish not only these people but innocent children and babies who did nothing wrong? I can’t understand at all as I’m writing this, still feeling sporadic aftershocks at M6 level at epicenter 100 miles away.

Answer (score 1):

One of the blessed things about England, is that it has an extremely low incidence of natural disasters.

If we have a magnitude 3 earthquake, it's front page news.

So such sayings are uncommon here, doom-laden sayings tend to be about God.  In Christianity, it always seems that everything is apparently God's fault, good or bad.

Comment: I would say that in Christianity everything is God's will, not fault! :)

Comment: @nico: Well, if it's His intention, then if it is bad, it's His fault! ;-) [As an atheist, like more Britons, I can say this without fear of smiting.]

Comment: @Orbling: In your answer you said "in Christianity;" therefore, the affirmation is not exactly correct. In Christianity, it's God will.

Comment: @Orbling: as an atheist you should not say that an event is in anyway related to God at all! Anyhow, as much as I can agree with your point of view, I also think you will not find one single instance in the Bible where they mention that something is "God's fault"!

Comment: @nico: That is my use of words, not the Bible's.  I can use whatever word intention I feel appropriate.  The Bible's word usage does not dictate to the non-Christian masses.  Thank God.

Comment: You're missing my point. If you say "In Christianity..." you're implying that what follows is the point of view of Christianity, whether you accept it or not.If you want to speak with your point of view then you should use "from an atheist point of view". It's like saying "In the Islamic culture, you shouldn't eat pork for sanitary reasons".Sure, that's the historical reason for it, but it's NOT the *cultural* reason Muslims believe in.You should rather say "In the Islamic culture, you shouldn't eat pork, because it's impure", even if you're a bacon lover!

Comment: @nico: The introduction of the word "seems" in my original statement removes that requirement, I am not stating their view, but my view of their view.  My statement was based on my first comment, rather than my answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll pass you this one :)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: See my point above, as you brought up the same point as nico.

Comment: @orbl **doom-laden sayings tend to be about God**  Hmm, what is an example of the type of saying you mean there?

Comment: @Joe Blow: Did you down vote me?  What for?  There's nothing questionable about what I said with regard to the question.

Comment: @Orbl Bonjour, I am innocent!  But I was wondering some examples of what you mean (see previous comment).  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a saying in English that invokes a father as a thing of fear. I just did a couple of searches on wikiquote, for "fear father", "terrible father" and "fearsome father" and none of them came up with anything relevant.

Fathers certainly can be fearsome, and there are many examples in English literature; and there are sayings about meting out punishment to children, such as "Spare the rod and spoil the child"; but the figure of a father as someone to be feared does not seem to have been enshrined in any proverbs or sayings that I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

"Lions, and tigers, and bears.  Oh, my!"